# Does lock(x) { } time out in C#? (Trying to force unit tests to run serially)

Tags: c#, locking

I've got some C# Unit Tests that must run serially because they clean the whole database and setting up a specified state. Doing this in parallel causes unpredictable behaviour. For that reason I tried to set the number of parallel tests to 1 in the XML, but it still did parallel tests. So my next approach was to use `[TestInitialize()]` and `[TestCleanup()]` Methods/Extensions to force serial processing.

Here is my code:

```
    static Object exclusiveDbAccess = new Object();

    //Use TestInitialize to run code before running each test
    [TestInitialize()]
    public void MyTestInitialize()
    {
        lock (exclusiveDbAccess)
        {
            Monitor.Enter(exclusiveDbAccess);
        }
    }

    //
    //Use TestCleanup to run code after each test has run
    [TestCleanup()]
    public void MyTestCleanup()
    {
        lock (exclusiveDbAccess)
        {
            Monitor.Exit(exclusiveDbAccess);
        }
    }
```

This seems to work most of the time, but I had (even this is very seldom) effects that looked like there were still some parallel tests running.
As this happened always when there was a lot of load on the computer, I was wondering if this wasn't caused by a time out of the "lock()" (e.g. after 10 or 30 seconds). For example, if the lock () block would be skipped after unsuccessfully trying to acquire the lock for x seconds, this could cause these problems.

So I would like some expert to tell me the exact behavior of that "lock" statement. Please do not just post any "guesses". In case lock() is known to time out experience reports are of course welcome...

Answer (score 2):

that seems like a wrong usage to me.

`lock(syncObject) { somecode }`

basically does the same as

```
Monitor.Enter(syncObject);
try { somecode } 
finally { Monitor.Exit(syncObject); }
```

so it does not seem right to do `lock` and `Monitor.Enter`/`Monitor.Exit` on the same object

neither of those should timeout, unless you explicitly set some timeout (like `Monitor.TryEnter(syncObject, timeout)`)

see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.Monitor.aspx)+

Comment: Thank you for the additional info about Monitor.TryEnter(). This gives implicitly a strong hint that Monitor.Enter() should never time out because there is a special method for that.

Answer (score 1):

They don't time out - but you shouldn't be using `lock` *and* `Monitor.Enter()`.

You should do it like this:

```
static Object exclusiveDbAccess = new Object();

//Use TestInitialize to run code before running each test
[TestInitialize()]
public void MyTestInitialize()
{
    Monitor.Enter(exclusiveDbAccess);
}

//
//Use TestCleanup to run code after each test has run
[TestCleanup()]
public void MyTestCleanup()
{
    Monitor.Exit(exclusiveDbAccess);
}
```

A `lock` statement of the form

```
lock (x) ...
```

is implemented exactly like this:

```
System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(x);
try {
    ...
}
finally {
    System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(x);
}
```

(From the C# Language specification, section 8.12)

Comment: Hm, when I tried to use only Monitor.Enter() / Exit() this resulted in an exception... something about incorrect state.; But if this is the "definition", just using the Monitor makes sense.

Comment: Seems to work without lock(), after a clean/rebuild of the project. However, I had errors when just building/running the tests after I just commented out the "lock". The exception did not occur, but the locking did not work without clean/rebuild, thought.